# Model alloy for series and parallel electric circuit

Tags: analyzer, alloy

I am newbie in alloy .
i need help for series and parallel electric circuit in alloy . 
I had model a graph for series circuit but when I omit self loop in series it does not  work 
  also it show only one instance for the series . i have to show when switch is on ,bulbs in series are on ... so their  is signature of state and On and Off extends state..

my code is :

```
abstract sig state{}

one sig on extends state{}

one sig off extends state{}

sig CE{}

//one sig battery extends CE{}


abstract sig bulb extends CE{
bs : one state
}

abstract sig switch extends CE{
ss : one state
}

sig Circuit{
battery: one CE,
/*eles: set state,
battery:one eles,   
switch : set eles,
bulb : set eles,
wire: eles one-> one eles*/
wire: CE->CE
}{
//all e:CE | #(e.wire)=1 and #(wire.e)=1
battery.^wire=CE
//no iden & wire
//all e:CE | e->e not in wire
}

pred show{}

run show for 1 Circuit,  5 CE
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to start with something really tiny and simple. For example, you could have wires, batteries and bulbs, and subset bulbs into bulbs that are on or off. One thing that looks wrong with your model: it won't be good enough just to have wires connect to elements: you'll need to identify which side of the element the wire is connected to.